# Regular expression match !

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find for the string of the format **abc1234**. I can compare character taking at each index whether is alpha or numeric and get the result. Instead wrote for a pattern match but couldn't succeed. Could some one know me where I am going wrong ?

```
var clid = "mxv4013" ;
if(clid.match("/[a-z]{3}(?=[0-9]{4})/i") != null){
    alert("success") ;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the quotes, JavaScript has regex literals:

```
var clid = "mxv4013" ;
if(clid.match(/[a-z]{3}(?=[0-9]{4})/i)){
    alert("success") ;
}
```

You can also remove the `!= null` check - `match` will return a true value on success and a falsy value on fail. In addition, the look-ahead is a little strange, you can use `/[a-z]{3}\d{4}/i`, or, to validate the whole string and avoid partial matching, `/^[a-z]{3}\d{4}$/i`.

Comment: @kobi - You are correct. But what was I doing earlier? I don't understand and have just started learning JS ;)

Comment: @Mahesh - In JavaScript, you can create a regex using a string. You could have written `.match("[a-z]{3}(?=[0-9]{4})", "i")`, but it isn't common, and I'm not sure all browsers support it. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: @Kobi - I understood it wrongly as `(?=` should definitely be used for some thing to be followed. So, `/[a-z]{3}\d{4}/i` means any string with 3 chars followed by 4 numbers is a match. Right ?

Comment: @Kobi - Just confusing from my C++ knowledge where string should be enclosed in `" "`. Incidentally thought that the pattern is also a string and so enclosed it in `""`. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh - Correct about the lookahead - but keep in ming, it will *not* match the digits in that case, just *check they are there*.

Comment: @Mahesh - string should be enclosed in single or double quotes in JavaScript. `/abc/` *isn't a string*, it is a **regex literal**, but like `"abc"` is a string literal, and `3` is a numeric literal.

Comment: @Kobi: The `.match("regex", "i")` syntax from your first comment does not work as you expect. `String.match()` accepts only one parameter, which can either be a regex literal (or regex object) or a string (which is passed to the RegExp constructor). The second `"i"` parameter is simply ignored. Otherwise excellent answer. +1

Comment: @ridgerunner - Thanks! I've tested it in Firefox 4.0, and `i` had an effect (`"hello".match("LL", "i")` matches `ll`, while `"hello".match("LL")` doesn't). That surprised and confused me, and I couldn't find anything documented, so I played safe and added the cross-browser warning. Looks like it was a good idea `:)`

Answer (score 3):

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) takes a regexp instead of a string for its parameter.

You are looking for:

```
'mxv4013'.match(/[a-z]{3}(?=[0-9]{4})/i)
```

Or, more simply:

```
'mxv4013'.match(/[a-z]{3}\d{4})/i)
```

Comment: Hmm, `\w` also matches digits and underscores, but `\d` is nicer.

Comment: You need `^` and `$` anchors for this to work for validation. The regex: `/[a-z]{3}\d{4})/i` matches this: `&^@%#abcdefg01234567(*%&#&`